# Change dataframe column values into rows if column names match

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I normalized a json object into a dataframe using `json_normalize` which looks something like this:

```
ID Name     Email_id      ID Name Email_id     ID Name  Email_id
1   A      A@gmail.com     2  B    B@gmail.com  3  C    C@gmail.com
```

I wanna convert the column values into rows like this:-

```
ID   Name   Email_id
1     A      A@gmil.com
2     B      B@gmail.com
3     C      C@gmail.com
```

but I'm not able to do that. I tried `pd.melt()` but it gives me `Data must be 1-dimensional` exception.

Comment: Can you post your original json object?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do that due to company's confidential data :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select only one column, but because duplicated columns names are selected all columns with same label, then convert to `1d` numpy array and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print (df['ID'])
   ID  ID  ID
0   1   2   3

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df['ID'].to_numpy().ravel(),
                   'Name': df['Name'].to_numpy().ravel(),
                   'Email_id': df['Email_id'].to_numpy().ravel()})
print (df)
   ID Name     Email_id
0   1    A  A@gmail.com
1   2    B  B@gmail.com
2   3    C  C@gmail.com
```

Another idea is create `MultiIndex` in columns by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
s = df.columns.to_series()

df.columns = [s, s.groupby(s).cumcount()]
print (df)

  ID Name     Email_id ID Name     Email_id ID Name     Email_id
   0    0            0  1    1            1  2    2            2
0  1    A  A@gmail.com  2    B  B@gmail.com  3    C  C@gmail.com

df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
      Email_id  ID Name
0  A@gmail.com   1    A
1  B@gmail.com   2    B
2  C@gmail.com   3    C
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do know such data structure is consistent, you can just slice the data by index, then concatenate them:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i:i+3] for i in range(0, df.shape[1], 3)])
```

To make sure to get the column IDs:

```
import numpy as np

# Get the target indexes
idx = np.arange(df.shape[1])[df.columns=='ID']
idx = np.append(idx, df.shape[1])

# Slice and concatenate data
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)])
```

Comment: This is an awesome method Caina, thank you so much :))

Comment: Happy to help! =)